# How can I monitor power usage via the CLI?

Tags: raspbian, power, terminal, battery

On Ubuntu, there is a way to monitor power usage by a Linux device via the CLI and inside the task manager if it's a laptop. I am powering my Pi via a lead-acid battery, and I'd like to have a continuous digital way to monitor power usage, without having to use a multimeter or something analog.

Is there something similar I can do on Raspbian?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you cannot, unless you're ready to solder some external ADC converters to I<sup>2</sup>C or serial and write scripts that will read the data.

there are NO embedded ADC converters on Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1):

The [MoPi](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/hamishcunningham/mopi-mobile-and-24-7-power-for-the-raspberry-pi) board would do the 12 V power conversion and provide battery monitoring capability to the Pi. Without a separate circuit there's no way to do it.